# How can I update an existing ruby installation to support additional OSs?

Tags: linux, installation, ruby, make

I have an existing ruby 2.5.1 installation that was created sometime back by compiling from source.

The installation is in afs and is accessed by several operating systems (linux-RH6 on x86 and aix on Power). When I created the installation I did the following:

On an linux system I ran

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-load-relative --disable-install-doc --prefix=/afs/foo/ruby/2.5.1 --exec-prefix=/afs/foo/2.5.1/linux
make 
make install
```

On an aix system I ran similar command:

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-load-relative --disable-install-doc --prefix=/afs/foo/ruby/2.5.1 --exec-prefix=/afs/foo/2.5.1/aix
make 
make install
```

**Note:** That each configure specified a different **--exec-prefix** so that arch dependent files are in different sub-directories.  afs has support that works with symbolic links to allow each OS to point to the "same" bin directory but pick up the correct arch dependent bin.

So I end up with all the non-arch dependent code shared and the arch dependent code in separate sub-directories.
Since then I have install a number of gems.

Now I would like to add support for other operating systems,  such as linux (RH7) on x86 and linux (RH7) on Power.

I still have the existing tar file used to install the existing installation so my thoughts were I should be able to just repeat this process by running a similar command on the new operating systems but using a unique --exe-prefix for each.

My concern is that since I have added gems since the original install will this break anything?
I am guessing if a gem gets broken I can simply re-install it?
I really just want to install the arch dependent files if possible.

For example is there some way to tell configure or make to only install the arch dependent files and not overwrite the non-arch dependent files?

Comment: Why not just uninstall the whole compiled from source Ruby and the Gems and just use [RVM](https://rvm.io) instead?

Comment: Note: cross-site dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59229735/2988

Comment: @JörgWMittag it was suggested I move the question here,  I just deleted it off of SO

Comment: @JakeGould The existing install is a multi-user environment that is in "production" ie there could be any number of scripts with #!/afs/foo/ruby/2.5.1/bin/ruby as there first line which I would like to not break.

Comment: @nPN Fair enough.